# Insert a value in a linked-list

Tags: r, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a linked list in R. I can easily add at the end and remove the values anywhere but I don't know how can I insert a value after or before another value ? Look at my code:

```
lis <- list()  
lis <- c(lis, (rnorm(1000000, mean = 30, sd=8)))    

lis[[170000]] <- 32   #add (replace) why??? this is my problem  
lis[[1000001]] <- 30  #add at the end  

lis <- lis[-880987]   #remove   
lis <- lis[-1000001]  #remove
```

Comment: Do you want `?append` . For a smaller example, `lis = as.list(1:4) ; append(lis, 100, 2)`

Comment: You could slice before and after the index and reconstruct the list with ```c()``` or ```list()```, although I doubt it's the most efficient.

Comment: Fyi, R is not the sort of programming language where you can easily create/"implement" new data structures from pointers and whatnot; and `list` does not mean linked list, rather an array.

Answer (score 0):

I havent asnwered anything in forever so you may have a little overkill here. But to shed light on the issue, The reason for the 'replacing' is because in your code `lis[[170000]] <- 32` is assigning the value `32` to the `170000` "slot" within the list. That's how object assignment works in `R`. 
What you should consider is in plain terms:
"If my list has 4 items, and I want to add a new item in second position, I should now have a list with 5 items"
Agnostic of list length or item position; adding anything will always increase the size of that thing.

Below is quick and ugly function.

PS: If you want to remove an item from a list you should use `lis[[444]]<-NULL` which will SUBTRACT the item out of the list

```
> lis[[1]]
[1] 30.60196
> lis[[1]] <- NULL
> lis[[1]]
[1] 26.61327
```

Or to show how to remove multiple values at once you can 
use `L[c(-n, -n2, ...)]`

```
> lis[1:4]
[[1]]
[1] 26.61327

[[2]]
[1] 31.98159

[[3]]
[1] 18.90489

[[4]]
[1] 39.47367

> lis[1:4] %>% {
+     .[c(-1, -3)]
+ }
[[1]]
[1] 31.98159

[[2]]
[1] 39.47367
```

### Here's a solution script with notes etc.

```
lis <- list()

lis <- c(lis, (rnorm(1000000, mean = 30, sd=8)))

#' @param L the list object
#' @param insert_val the new value to insert into the list
#' @param insert_n the nth position of the list to insert
#'   the \code{insert_val} into
#'   
#'   
#' This function essentially takes the initial list object
#' and breaks it into two sections. The first item through
#' the lag(-1) position of the new \code{insert_n}, 
#' and then the \code{insert_n} position through the lists
#' total length when passed into the function.
#' 
#' To show basically if we wante to put a new value into
#' a list somewhere... call it position 3 and value 976:
#' Starting list
#' - List
#'  -- 433
#'  -- 5454
#'  -- 17
#'  -- 887
#' 
#' Part the list
#' - List1
#'  -- 433
#'  -- 5454
#' - Variable
#'  -- 976
#' - List2
#'  -- 17
#'  -- 887
#'  
#' c(List1, Variable, List2)
#'  
#' - List
#'  -- 433
#'  -- 5454
#'  -- 976
#'  -- 17
#'  -- 887
#'  
#'  
f <- function(L = NULL, insert_val = NULL, insert_n = NULL){

  if(!is.list(L)){
    L <- as.list(L)
  }

  l.max <- length(L)

  # If no position provided or if it's `1`
  # it goes to the first position...
  if(is.null(insert_n)||insert_n <= 1){

    L <- c(insert_val, L)

    # If new position greater than current length
    # it goes to the end
  }else if(insert_n > l.max){

    L <- append(L, insert_val)

  }else if(insert_n <= l.max){
    part_one <- L[1:(insert_n - 1)]
    part_two <- L[(insert_n):(l.max)]
    L <- c(part_one, insert_val, part_two)
  }

  return(L)

}
```

### And testing

```
LL <- as.list(1:10)
> dput(LL)
list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L) # length 10
> dput(f(L = LL, insert_n = 4, insert_val = "hi!"))
list(1L, 2L, 3L, "hi!", 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L) # length 11
```

And if the nth position is greater than the list:

```
 > dput(f(L = LL, insert_n = 500, insert_val = "hi!"))
    list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, "hi!")
```

If it's less than or `NULL`

```
> dput(f(L = LL, insert_n = -4, insert_val = "hi!"))
list("hi!", 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L)
```